# Removing unwanted characters from a string element in a ruby array

Tags: ruby, oop

If I have the following array...

```
["a =>", "b => c", "c => f", "d => a", "e => b", "f =>"]
```

How might I get it to return...

```
["a", "b", "c", "c", "f", "d", "a", "e", "b", "f"]
```

I thought to iterate through with `.map` & use `.tr` or `.gsub` but I can never get it quite right...

Comment: Presumable, your array is an example. Could it look like this: `["ab => cd", "cd => ef", ...]`?

Comment: Rarely can you ask an unambiguous question in terms of a single example. I assume your array is an example because there is nothing to do if it concerns a single, specific array. The reader needs to know the possible forms of the array and desired return value. For example, some of the answers assume that, as in the example, each element of the array is the form `"x =>y"`, where `x` is a lowercase letter and `y` is an empty string or a space followed by one lowercase letter. Are there other possibilities? You need to state your question in words, with examples used for clarification.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you just want the letters of the string:

```
arr = ["a =>", "b => c", "c => f", "d => a", "e => b", "f =>"]
arr.flat_map { |str| str.scan(/\w+/) }
=> ["a", "b", "c", "c", "f", "d", "a", "e", "b", "f"]
```

The regex `\w` says only match against a letter, number or underscore.

Comment: You can use `flat_map { ... }` instead of `map { ... }.flatten`

Comment: Ah yes, nice suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
arr = ["a =>", "b => c", "c => f", "d => a", "e => b", "f =>"]

arr.join(' ').scan(/\w/) 
OR
arr.join(' ').scan(/\w+/) 


=> ["a", "b", "c", "c", "f", "d", "a", "e", "b", "f"]
```

There is a nice website called Rubular (http://rubular.com/) where you can interactively test out variety of regular expressions against strings. It also lists "Regex quick reference" so you can learn about the regex you often see used in Ruby code.

Answer (score 1):

```
["a =>", "b => c", "c => f", "d => a", "e => b", "f =>"].join.gsub(/=>| /, '').chars
# => ["a", "b", "c", "c", "f", "d", "a", "e", "b", "f"]

["a =>", "b => c", "c => f", "d => a", "e => b", "f =>"].join.gsub(/[^a-z]/, '').chars
# => ["a", "b", "c", "c", "f", "d", "a", "e", "b", "f"]
```

So I join the strings together ([Array#join](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-join)), replace chars you don't want with an empty string ([String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)) and split the result string into its chars ([String#chars](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-chars)).

Comment: You've assumed there is no element `"ab => c"`. Do we know that?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the possible form of the array and the desired return value, neither of which are made clear by the question, you could do the following.

```
arr = ["a_1 =>", "b 2 => cc3", "cc3 => f6", "d4 => a_1", "e5 => b 2", "f6 =>"]

arr.flat_map { |str| str.split /\s*=>\s*/ }
  #=> ["a_1", "b 2", "cc3", "cc3", "f6", "d4", "a_1", "e5", "b 2", "f6"]
```

None of the other answers given to date return the same value for this array.